# Transposing specific columns after groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, transpose, multi-index

I know there are millions of similar questions in Stackoverflow but I checked a lot of them and couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I am replicating my data below,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['1', '2',
                              '3', '4','5','6','7'],
                   'Manager': ["James","James","James", "Jason", "Kirk", "Lars", "Lars"],
                   'weekno': [25, 25,25,25,25,25,25],
                   'monthno': [6, 6,6,6,6,6,6]})
```

What I want to is to first group them under month, then week as kind of a pivot table, then in rows Manager Names and count of their IDs. (ID represents unique, equipment IDs, so I want to see how many equipments different managers have)

```
df=df.groupby(['monthno','weekno','Manager']).agg({'ID':'count'})
```

this code above is a good start but I can not transpose only monthno and weekno columns, when I add .T at the end, it transposes everything as expected.

I am creating the expected output in excel(I have just randomised the numbers):
[image: Desired Output]

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: I am editing the first post

Comment: Have you tried using pandas function pivot?

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 no I haven't, I didnt know about such function, but I will check. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using pandas.pivot_table and applying the agg function on the pivot table object.

```
pandas.pivot_table(df,index='Manager', columns = ['Month No','Count of ID,'Week No'],aggfunc = {'ID':'count'})
```

If the columns being transposed, arent in that wanted orderly fashion. It may help, to take a look at the stack and unstack functions https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html